# Array<String> does not have a member named 'contains' in swift

Tags: swift

Can I use the contains method on an Array or do I have to instead use the filter method and loop through with a check?

Given ignores is an `Array<String>`

e.g.

```
    return self.ignores.filter({ (user) -> Bool in
        user == username
    }).count > 0
```

or

```
    return self.ignores.contains(username);
```

Comment: Note that the syntax changed between Swift 1.2 and Swift 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
contains(ignores, username)
```